# R runs out of memory plotting data frame with ggplot2

Tags: r, linux, ggplot2, r-raster

I'm running R on Fedora 31 on a Dell XPS laptop with 8Gb RAM. I'm attempting to plot [this GeoTIFF](https://www.worldpop.org/geodata/summary?id=6324) using ggplot2, so that I can overlay other data using code I've already written with ggplot2. I've been roughly following [this lesson](https://datacarpentry.org/r-raster-vector-geospatial/01-raster-structure/) on working with raster data in R. After converting the TIFF into a RasterLayer into a data frame, the R program fails when loading the data frame with ggplot2, simply outputting "Killed" and exiting.

Here is a minimal code sample that produces this error:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(raster)
library(rgdal)

afg_pop <- raster("afg_ppp_2020.tif")
pop_df <- as.data.frame(afg_pop, xy = TRUE)

ggplot() +
    # This is the line that results with the error: "Killed"
    geom_raster(data = pop_df , aes(x = x, y = y, fill = afg_ppp_2020))
```

Running `dmesg` reveals that R ran out of memory:

```
 [20563.603882] Out of memory: Killed process 42316 (R) total-vm:11845908kB, anon-rss:6878420kB, file-rss:4kB, shmem-rss:0kB, UID:1000 pgtables:19984kB oom_score_adj:0
```

It's hard for me to believe that even with a data file this large R is running out of the memory required to handle it. Why does R need so much memory to perform this task, and more importantly what other method can I use to plot this data, preferably using ggplot2?

I'm relatively new to R, so please forgive me if I'm ignoring something obvious here. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot speak to the memory requirements of `ggplot` but the spatial resolution of the data is very high (~ 90m). There is no point in asking ggplot to draw 10955 (rows) * 17267 (columns) = 189,159,985 pixels as you won't be able to see them (unless, perhaps you are printing a billboard). So a simple workaround is to take a regular sample, or to aggregate

```
f <- "ftp://ftp.worldpop.org.uk/GIS/Population/Global_2000_2020/2020/AFG/afg_ppp_2020.tif"
if (!file.exists(basename(f))) download.file(f, basename(f), mode="wb")

library(raster)
afg_pop <- raster("afg_ppp_2020.tif")
pop_df <- data.frame(sampleRegular(afg_pop, 10000, xy=TRUE))

library(ggplot2)
ggplot() + geom_raster(data = pop_df , aes(x = x, y = y, fill = afg_ppp_2020))
```

A better alternative that takes a little longer

```
afg_pop2 <- aggregate(afg_pop, 10) # this takes some time
pop_df2 <- as.data.frame(afg_pop2, xy=TRUE)
ggplot() + geom_raster(data = pop_df2 , aes(x = x, y = y, fill = afg_ppp_2020))
```

The maps are not very nice; there are better options in other R packages for making maps.

Comment: Thanks Robert, this worked well for me. I'd be interested in what other packages are better for making maps like this; it was my impression that ggplot is a good choice for this type of layered GIS work.